# Schedule a task to run at everyday on a specific time

Tags: java, scheduled-tasks, quartz-scheduler

I am trying to execute specific work in my Servlet/JSP application in everyday at 8.00AM and 12.00 PM. The Quartz library seems to be ideal for this, so I tried using it.

I used both of the tutorials and examples in below links.

http://www.mkyong.com/java/quartz-2-scheduler-tutorial/

http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2012/07/quartz-2-scheduler-example.html

Below is an attempt

**Job class**

```
import org.quartz.Job;
import org.quartz.JobExecutionContext;
import org.quartz.JobExecutionException;

public class HelloJob implements Job
{
    public void execute(JobExecutionContext context)
    throws JobExecutionException {

        System.out.println("Hello Quartz!");    

    }

}
```

**Trigger class**

```
import org.quartz.JobBuilder;
import org.quartz.JobDetail;
import org.quartz.Scheduler;
import org.quartz.SimpleScheduleBuilder;
import org.quartz.Trigger;
import org.quartz.TriggerBuilder;
import org.quartz.impl.StdSchedulerFactory;

public class SimpleTriggerExample {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {



        JobDetail job = JobBuilder.newJob(HelloJob.class)
            .withIdentity("dummyJobName", "group1").build();



        // Trigger the job to run on the next round minute
        Trigger trigger = TriggerBuilder
            .newTrigger()
            .withIdentity("dummyTriggerName", "group1")
            .withSchedule(
                SimpleScheduleBuilder.simpleSchedule()
                    .withIntervalInSeconds(5).repeatForever())
            .build();

        // schedule it
        Scheduler scheduler = new StdSchedulerFactory().getScheduler();
        scheduler.start();
        scheduler.scheduleJob(job, trigger);

    }
}
```

However, both are not satisfying my need. They do not run at specific time. How can I use the Quarts to execute the job everyday 8.00AM and 12.00 PM?

Comment: From http://quartz-scheduler.org/generated/2.2.1/html/qs-all/#page/Quartz_Scheduler_Documentation_Set%2Fco-use_jobs_and_triggers.html%23: *SimpleTrigger is handy if you need 'one-shot' execution (just single execution of a job at a given moment in time), or if you need to fire a job at a given time, and have it repeat N times, with a delay of T between executions.
*CronTrigger is useful if you wish to have triggering based on calendar-like schedules such as “every Friday, at noon” or “at 10:15 on the 10th day of every month.”*

Comment: @JBNizet: OKKK...Any example plesae?

Comment: http://quartz-scheduler.org/api/2.2.0/org/quartz/CronScheduleBuilder.html Google is your friend. So is the documentation. I've never used quartz before, and it took me 3 minutes to find it.

Comment: @JBNizet: Problem is not the sceduler. The way it should be scheduled. In MKYONG tutorial, he has given an example, but it seems like it is kind of expression I am not familiar with.

Comment: Have you read the documentation I linked to. It contains an example which uses `.withSchedule(dailyAtHourAndMinute(10, 0))`. You don't even need to read the javadoc to guess what that does.

Comment: @JBNizet: anyway, the hours are mentioned in 24 hour clock?

Comment: http://quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.x/cookbook/DailyTrigger

Comment: @JBNizet: another question. In above example, we have directly called the class. But in servlets, you know, the calling class will be written separatly. so what we do there? Make the calling class a `ServletListener` so it will be invoked automatically?

Comment: If you want some code to be executed when the application is deployed, a ServletContextListener is the right tool.

Comment: @JBNizet:Not when the app is deployed, but to run automatically (so yeah, something like run always), without our specific calling.

Comment: Err, how could code in an app run if the app is not deployed?

Comment: @JBNizet: I think I got your point. What you meant is that once the app is deployed, the listener will start working from that time onwards right? I got it another way, I thought only as soon as the app is deployed then the listener stops.

Comment: A listener doesn't *run* or *stop*. Its `contextInitialized()` method is called when the application is deployed, and its `contextDestroyed()` method is called when the application is undeployed. You decide what to do in both cases. And in this case, the `contextInitialized()` method would create a schedule a job and start the scheduler.

Answer (score 1):

Try create a schedule with Cron:

```
    Trigger trigger = TriggerBuilder
            .newTrigger()
            .withIdentity("triggerName","triggerGroup")
           .withSchedule(CronScheduleBuilder.cronSchedule("0 0 12 * * ?")).build();

    Trigger trigger = TriggerBuilder
            .newTrigger()
            .withIdentity("triggerName","triggerGroup")
           .withSchedule(CronScheduleBuilder.cronSchedule("0 0 8 * * ?")).build();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Trigger trigger = TriggerBuilder
            .newTrigger()
            .withIdentity("triggerName","triggerGroup")
           .withSchedule(CronScheduleBuilder.cronSchedule("0 30 12 * * ?")).build(); //schedules a job for 12:30am

    Trigger trigger = TriggerBuilder
            .newTrigger()
            .withIdentity("triggerName","triggerGroup")
           .withSchedule(CronScheduleBuilder.cronSchedule("0 0 14 * * ?")).build(); //schedules a job for 2pm
```

Use this site for great information on scheduling:
http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.x/tutorials/crontrigger.html

Answer (score 0):

```
ITrigger trigger = TriggerBuilder.Create()
  .WithIdentity("reportTrigger").WithSchedule(CronScheduleBuilder.DailyAtHourAndMinute(23,0)).Build();
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.